# Working with month/day/hours/minutes/seconds in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How would you refactor this?

```js
 var myDate = new Date()
 var myYear = myDate.getFullYear()
 var myMonth = myDate.getMonth()
 if (myMonth < 10) {
  myMonth = '0' + myMonth
 }
 var myDay = myDate.getDate()
 if (myDay < 10) {
  myDay = '0' + myDay
 }
 var myHour = myDate.getHours()
 if (myHour < 10) {
  myHour = '0' + myHour
 }
 var myMinute = myDate.getMinutes()
 if (myMinute < 10) {
  myMinute = '0' + myMinute
 }
 var mySecond = myDate.getSeconds()
 if (mySecond < 10) {
  mySecond = '0' + mySecond
 }
document.getElementById('myDate').innerHTML = myYear + myMonth + myDay + myHour + myMinute + mySecond
```

```html
<div id="myDate"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I recommend using a library like momentjs.com , with it you can format such as moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the moment.js library, you can reduce the formatting rules to a single line.

See the [moment.js display Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) for details.  Note that there is an difference with the existing code: JavaScript stores months from 0-11, meaning October is stored as 9, while most likely, we want to show "10".

```js
var myDate = new Date();

document.getElementById('momentFormatted').innerHTML =
  moment(myDate).format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss");

var myYear = myDate.getFullYear()
var myMonth = myDate.getMonth()
if (myMonth < 10) {
  myMonth = '0' + myMonth
}
var myDay = myDate.getDate()
if (myDay < 10) {
  myDay = '0' + myDay
}
var myHour = myDate.getHours()
if (myHour < 10) {
  myHour = '0' + myHour
}
var myMinute = myDate.getMinutes()
if (myMinute < 10) {
  myMinute = '0' + myMinute
}
var mySecond = myDate.getSeconds()
if (mySecond < 10) {
  mySecond = '0' + mySecond
}
document.getElementById('myDate').innerHTML = myYear + myMonth + myDay + myHour + myMinute + mySecond
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDate"></div>
<hr>
With Moment.js:
<div id="momentFormatted"></div>
```